# Given $u$, a subharmonic function near $0$, proof that $u(z^k)$ is also subharmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, potential-theory

I am following Thomas Ransford's book *Potential Theory on the Complex Plane*. I am stuck with exercise 2.4.2.i, page 39:

> Show that if $u(z)$ is subharmonic on a neighborhood of $0$, then so is $u(z^k)$ for each $k\geq 1$.

I solved 2.4.2.ii and 2.4.2.iii, but the above proposition is still "unsolved". Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Show that if $u$ subharmonic, $f$ holomorphic, $u \circ f$ is subharmonic (assuming it is defined on an open set etc); using the majorization by harmonic functions criterion, the result is immediate once you know that if $v$ harmonic, $f$ holomorphic, $v \circ f$ is harmonic, but it is fun to do it using the Laplacian too and assuming $u$ is $C^2$ and verify that if $\nabla u \ge 0$ then $\nabla (u \circ f) \ge 0$

Comment: Thanks!! But the idea of the problem is to serve as a partial lemma in order to obtain $u\circ f$ is subharmonic.

Comment: I actually looked at the book as I realized I have it in my library and I see what you are saying; another idea is to show that the mean inequality holds at $0$ for $r <\rho^k$ (where $\rho$ is the one from the fact that $u$ is subharmonic at $0$) for $u(z^k)$ (immediate by changing variables $t \to kt$ and using periodicty of $e^{it}$, while for all other points in a small neighborhood of zero, $z \to z^k$ is actually conformal so one can apply Corollary 2.4.3 as $z \to z^k$ is a legitimate change of variable there (on a very small neighborhood that avoids $0$)

Comment: @Conrad, thanks a lot!! Your idea looks promising.

Comment: hopefully now is clear - again idea is to split into $z=0, z \ne 0$ and show mean inequality on small enough neighborhoods; for $z=0$ direct, for $z \ne 0$ Corrolary 2.4.3 as $z \to z^k$ is conformal if the neighborhood is very small and avoids $0$

Comment: I thought the same as you in the case $z\neq 0$, because of the conformal properties of power maps away from the origin. Thanks again.

Comment: happy to be of help